# how can I modify a canvas text from another thread in tkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

Well, I'm so lost. I'm doing an application with tkinter that shows on the GUI parameters that come from an Arduino (I split the variables on the serial and bla bla). BUT if I want to show, for example, real time (updating on real time), I have the error **"main thread is not in main loop"**.
*I managed to modify the text from another thread having used threading*, but for some reason I can't set the time from datatime.

This is my code

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=1)
pressure = ""
OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)

class ReadSerial(threading.Thread):
  loop = True
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.start()
    self.loop = True

  def callback(self):
    self.loop = False

  def run(self):
    
    # Read and record the data
        while(self.loop):
            if ser.isOpen():
                input_data=ser.readline().strip().decode("utf-8")
                pressure = input_data.split(",")[0] #OBTENER    PRESION, INDICE 0
                temperature = input_data.split(",")[1] #OBTENER TEMPERATURA, INDICE 1
                canvas.itemconfig(presion, text = pressure+"hPa")
                canvas.itemconfig(temp, text = temperature+"°C")
                #ALL OF THE ABOVE WORKS, BUT IF I DO THIS DOESN'T WORKS
                canvas.itemconfig(hora, text = time.strftime(%H:%M:%S))
                            
   #tkinter code, not important
   window = Tk()
   window.geometry("1366x768")
   window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF").....
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what you need to do, ensure that your thread is in your `tkinter mainloop`. Maybe read through [this tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-thread/) to help you understand this issue.

Comment: @Rory if you check my code, I've do it exactly like in the tutorial I think. I said that my thread works, because it read the Arduino serial and updates the text, but when I use the datatime or time library, the code shows that error

Comment: @Rory after you tell me that, I figured out that my thread runs 2sec after the mainloop. I put it in 0 and it works, thank you so much! Also, it runs soooo slowly :/ 80% CPU, is there a thing of my code or is the thread issues?

Comment: It is difficult to say, but you could certainly use the `timeit` module to analyze sections of the code that you suspect are taking longer than expected.  [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for how to implement it.  That might help you isolate the parts of your code that take the longest.